# Using cos() function in a for loop gets undefined reference to cos error

Tags: c, math, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Build error when getting the value of sin()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509925/c-build-error-when-getting-the-value-of-sin)

I am trying to integrate a function using 100 intervals within the period, so I'm using a for loop.  The function contains cos(stuff here), but it won't run within the for loop for some reason.  If I move it out of the for loop, it works fine.  I have #include , so I don't understand.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//float t = 0.000000;
double T = .001;
int n = 100;
double pi = 3.141592654;
double a[5];
double b[5];
double function_results[100];
double anfunction_results[100];
double bnfunction_results[100];
double final = 0.000000000000;
double anfinal = 0.000000000;
double k = 0.000000;
double function(float t){
double f = 3*pow(t,2);
return f;
}

int main()
{   

//double w = 2*pi/T;
double h = T/n;
int i = 1;

for(; i<100; i++){
    double iterate = -T/2 + h*i;
    function_results[i] = function(iterate);
    final = final + function_results[i];
}

a[0] = (h/3)*(function(-T/2) + final+function(T/2))/T;
printf("%.12f \n",a[0]);

int p = 1;
int l = 1;
for(; l<=5; l++){
for(; p<100; p++){
    double iteration = -T/2 + h*p;
    k = l+.0000001;
    anfunction_results[p] =     3*pow(iteration,2)*cos(k*iteration*2.00000*pi/T*pi/180.00000);
    anfinal = anfunction_results[p] + anfinal;
}
a[l] = (2/T)*(h/3)*(3*pow(-T/2,2)*cos(-T/2.0000) + anfinal + 3*pow(T/2,2)*cos(k*T/2.00000*2.00000*pi/T*pi/180.00000));
}


//printf("%.12f \n",a[1]);
//printf("%.12f \n",a[2]);
//printf("%.12f \n",a[3]);
//printf("%.12f \n",a[4]);
//printf("%.12f \n",a[5]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have linked with `-lm` in both cases?

Comment: It works fine here in vc2008. What errors are you getting exactly, copy and paste them so we may help.

Comment: What's the expected output? It compiles fine on VC2010 and prints '0.000000085850', '0.000000171550', '0.000000171550', '0.000000171550', '0.000000171550' & '0.000000171550' if I activate the printf commands.

Comment: project_name.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `cos'

Comment: getting 3 of those.  Sorry, I hit enter to go down and it posted.

Comment: @HollisScriber Which Compiler/Platform?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably not linking to the math library.  Add `-lm` to your linker options.

(I don't know why it would "run fine" with `cos()` moved out of the `for` loop, but this explanation is not very clear on your part.  If you get an undefined reference for `cos()` in one part of the program, you should get it in a different part as well, if the compiler options are the same in both cases.)

Comment: Unless the argument to `cos` is a constant when he moves it outside the loop. Then the compiler evaluates it during compilation, and since `cos` is not called from the programme, there's no need to link the math library.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was not aware that compilers had an internal definition of `cos()` to use when folding constants. Interesting.

Comment: Got it.  I've found those how to link library tutorials, but I never realized they went in a settings pane somewhere, not the code itself.  Explains why I got so many errors.  Thanks!

Comment: Not all do that without optimisations turned on, though. I just tried, and clang gave an undefined reference for `cos(1.2)`, gcc evaluated it during compilation (but with `-O`, clang did too).